# Mono aspx error 500: System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule.Init not implemented

Tags: asp.net, centos7, mono

I have a CentOS 7 VM installed with all httpd / mysql packages etc.
I wanted to run a ticketsystem called SmarterTrack, which is build in ASPX.
Looked eveything up and installed the necessary packages I could find on internet (mono server and xsp).

Everything seems to be running fine now (mono server is running etc) but when I go to the website I get an error 500:

```
System.NotImplementedException
The method or operation is not implemented.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule.Init (System.Web.HttpApplication app) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/FileAuthorizationModule.cs:51 
  at System.Web.Configuration.HttpModulesSection.LoadModules (System.Web.HttpApplication app) [0x00052] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/HttpModulesSection.cs:82 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitOnce (Boolean full_init) [0x000a4] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:216
```

And in my httpd errorlog I see this:

```
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_testing.mydomain.com
Root directory: /var/www/clients/client1/web9/web/
Exception while initOnce: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule.Init (System.Web.HttpApplication app) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/FileAuthorizationModule.cs:51
  at System.Web.Configuration.HttpModulesSection.LoadModules (System.Web.HttpApplication app) [0x00052] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/HttpModulesSection.cs:82
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitOnce (Boolean full_init) [0x000a4] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:216
Please restart your app to unlock it
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: `The method or operation is not implemented.` Go find a Windows server to run this app.

Comment: Tried that but the application store keeps crashing when the website is being visited

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Mono doesn't have an implementation for the [(System.Web.Security)FileAuthorizationModule](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Security/FileAuthorizationModule.cs). As you can see in the content linked, the class is just there as a stub, so that compilation against it works, but it will not run properly at runtime.

After Microsoft released .NET sources with the MIT license, you could think that Mono could adopt [referencesource's sources for this class](https://github.com/mono/referencesource/blob/mono/System.Web/Security/FileAuthorizationModule.cs), however this is currently not possible because this class uses under the hood the UnsafeNativeMethods class, which gives a hint that it uses a non-cross-platform approach (Mono should however remain compatible with non-Windows platforms).